# How do I configure MySQL to save data on another volume?

Tags: mysql

I'm (re)installing MySQL 5.5.23 on my Mac (Snow Leopard) and since I have two volumes, one with much more space than the boot volume, I'd like to configure it to write all its data to the bigger volume instead of to the boot vol.

I tried moving the data dir to my other volume and using a symlink to it from the installation directory, but I wasn't able to set the ownership of the symlink to the same ownership as the directory originally had ... and MySQL no longer starts. I can't find logs to see what happens when it tries to startup, but I assume it dislikes something about my present arrangement.

Anybody have experience making this work?

ETA: I found this in my macbook.local.err file:

```
120423 13:01:21 [ERROR] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: Can't find file: './mysql/host.frm' (errno: 13)
120423 13:01:21 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Can't find file: './mysql/host.frm' (errno: 13)
...
^G/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: Can't find file: './mysql/plugin.frm' (errno: 13)
120423 14:16:55 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
```

Comment: Install MySQL to the bigger volume?

Comment: It says it must be installed to the same volume as the Mac OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit MySQL's `my.cnf` file so that it's `datadir` variable (the data directory, usually `/var/lib/mysql` on Linux machines) is set to a folder of the new volume.

Comment: Weirdly, I can't find it. I did a `locate my.cnf` and it returned several nonuseful results. Any idea where it should be on a Mac?

Comment: I did a little more digging and found that by default the OS X installation does not use a my.cnf, and MySQL just uses the default values, but you can copy one from /usr/local/mysql/support-files into the /etc dir. So I'll try this suggestion and see if it works. Thanks!

Comment: This worked, after I figured out why it was giving me the errors shown above in my question. What was failing was permissions. I needed to `chown` the dirs under the new location to `_mysql:wheel` (recursively) and then mysql was able to find host.frm and plugin.frm, and started up successfully. Thanks for the help!